# Chart.js how to resend animation command to a chart?

Tags: animation, chart.js

How to resend animation command like:

```
$('#my_select').on('change', function() {
    resend_animation_to_chart
});
```

Tnx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easyest way to do this is by removing all the data updating the chart, readding the data and the updating the chart again

```js
const chart = new Chart(ctx, options);

document.getElementById("tt").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const dataSets = chart.data.datasets;
  chart.data.datasets = [];
  chart.update();
  chart.data.datasets = dataSets;
  chart.update();
})
```

Live example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderWidth: 1,
      backgroundColor: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {}
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
const chart = new Chart(ctx, options);

document.getElementById("tt").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const dataSets = chart.data.datasets;
  chart.data.datasets = [];
  chart.update();
  chart.data.datasets = dataSets;
  chart.update();
})
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <button id="tt">
    Reanimate
    </button>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.3.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: No sorry I have a complex structure with 4 dynamic charts with dynamic data in each chart  
I choose one of them with a select sowing and hiding and I use jquery.
Last but not least I get data with an ajax post

Comment: Yeah, you must store the reference to those 4 charts so then you can still do this, that the data is dynamic does not matter since you remove the data but since you store it in a temp variable and place it right back it doesnt need to call your post again